# Unity 2020.1.3f1 won't build Android Project...totally stuck cannot solve these errors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am still completely stuck on this... everything worked fine on the last version of unity 2019 now ti is totally broken and I cannot do a build i get these errors, any help would be appreciated...I tried installing and uninstall the unity module, no effect... I cannot go back to the old as it won't open!!!:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
UnityEditor.Utils.Paths.Combine (System.String[] components) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Paths.cs:29)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidGradleRoot.GetGradleLaunchJarPath (System.String directory) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.GetBaseCommand (System.Int32 jvmHeapSize) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <5f8140421e7d41ada100b629c3033aa7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:324)
```

Then this one:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

this one:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00270] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Comment: Try this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1631097/android-build-error-value-cannot-be-null.html

Answer (score 0):

I went to file preferences and made sure I was using Unity's recommended Gradle installation (also I checked that box for the NDK and SDK and JDK)

Also in player settings I unchecked use custom Proguard file and Gradle file (not sure if this helped I am pretty sure it was the first option)